# C# project unable to load local.settings.json value

Tags: c#, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm executing the C# code(Program.cs) below in VS Code on MacOS, and I'm encountering an issue where the connection string value is returning null.

```cs
services
    .AddOptions<Myettings>()
    .Configure<IConfiguration>( (settings, configuration) => 
        configuration.GetSection( "MySection" ).Bind( settings ) );

var connectionString = hostBuilderContext.Configuration
    .GetConnectionString( "MyDatabase" );
```

This snippet runs perfectly in JetBrains Rider on Mac and Visual Studio on Windows. I suspect the problem lies with my VS Code configuration. Could anyone advise on how to correctly load, use, or set up the values from local.settings.json in VS Code?

I've installed the C# Dev Kit and followed a YouTube tutorial to set up, rebuild, and test the project, but I'm still unable to get my project running in VS code.

Here is my Demo Project:
https://github.com/Mingz6/DemoCSharpVSC.git

With dotnet 8, I have another issue to start the project.

Comment: Can you share more code from your Program.cs together with your local.setting.json ?

Comment: Sure thing. I created a project to have a isolate this issue and let me have better understanding.